# I wanna find an element in a webpage using Selenium and Python, how can I obtain the input value?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

So here's the segment of the website that I'm working with. Specifically I wanna obtain the value from . I can access the span class using `best_offer = driver.find_element_by_class_name('showBestOffer')` in Selenium, is there a way I can fetch the value inside the  tag?

```
<div class="ebayBestOfferAccepted" id="363858864519-bestOffer-simple"><div class="bestOfferSoldPrice" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"><span class="bestOfferData"><b>Best Offer Accepted Price:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></span><span class="bestOfferLink"><span class="showBestOffer"><input type="submit" value="15.00 USD"></span></span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
best_offer = driver.find_element_by_class_name('showBestOffer').get_text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

```
span = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span[class='showBestOffer']")
input = span.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")
bestOffer = input.get_attribute("value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath

```
input = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//span[@class="showBestOffer"]/input'))
val = input.get_attribute("value")
```